# derive column signal based on rsi value[Pandas,Numpy]

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, trading

i want to create **signal** column

*where rsi>80 signal column value sell, and*

*where rsi<20 signal column value buy, and*

want to filter for **overlap signal**,

already created column using np.where

low = where rsi<20 1 for true 0 for false

high = where rsi>80 -1 for true 0 for false

low+high = sum of low and high column, we can relate low+high value 1 for buy, -1 for sell, 0 for non,

but problem is we get overlap signal, if we map -1 to sell, and 1 for buy

and ever using diff() i am unable to generate without overlapping signal

```
RSI LOW HIGH  LOW+HIGH
79  0   0     0
80  0   0     0
80  0   0     0
81  0   -1    -1
60  0   0     0
19  1   0     1
19  1   0     1


Require Outout

RSI LOW HIGH  LOW+HIGH Signal 
79  0   0     0        0 
80  0   0     0        0   
80  0   0     0        0   
81  0   -1    -1       SELL  
60  0   0     0        0
19  1   0     1        BUY
19  1   0     1        0
30  0   0     0        0
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Calculate the RSI values for the data.
2. Create two columns with boolean values based on the RSI values: one for when RSI is less than 20 and another for when RSI is greater than 80. For example:

```py
df['low'] = np.where(df['rsi'] < 20, 1, 0)
df['high'] = np.where(df['rsi'] > 80, -1, 0)
```

3. Sum the low and high columns to get the signal column. A value of 1 indicates a "buy" signal, -1 indicates a "sell" signal, and 0 indicates no signal. For example:

```py
df['signal'] = df['low'] + df['high']
```

4. Use the `diff()` method to calculate the difference between consecutive values in the signal column. This will give you the changes in the signals over time. For example:

```py
df['signal_diff'] = df['signal'].diff()
```

5. Create a new column called `final_signal` to remove the overlapping signals. This can be done by setting the value to 1 `(buy)` when the signal column is greater than 0 and the `signal_diff` column is greater than or equal to 0, or by setting the value to -1 `(sell)` when the signal column is less than 0 and the `signal_diff` column is less than or equal to 0. Otherwise, the value is set to 0 (no signal). For example:

```py
df['final_signal'] = np.where((df['signal'] > 0) & (df['signal_diff'] >= 0), 1,
                     np.where((df['signal'] < 0) & (df['signal_diff'] <= 0), -1, 0))
```

full example

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Step 1: Calculate RSI values for the data
df = pd.DataFrame({'close': [100, 110, 90, 120, 130, 140, 110, 90, 80, 100, 120]})
n = 3
delta = df['close'].diff()
gain = delta.where(delta > 0, 0)
loss = -delta.where(delta < 0, 0)
avg_gain = gain.rolling(n).mean()
avg_loss = loss.rolling(n).mean()
rs = avg_gain / avg_loss
rsi = 100 - (100 / (1 + rs))
df['rsi'] = rsi

# Step 2: Create boolean columns for low and high RSI values
df['low'] = np.where(df['rsi'] < 20, 1, 0)
df['high'] = np.where(df['rsi'] > 80, -1, 0)

# Step 3: Sum low and high columns to get signal column
df['signal'] = df['low'] + df['high']

# Step 4: Calculate difference between consecutive signal values
df['signal_diff'] = df['signal'].diff()

# Step 5: Remove overlapping signals
df['final_signal'] = np.where((df['signal'] > 0) & (df['signal_diff'] >= 0), 1,
                     np.where((df['signal'] < 0) & (df['signal_diff'] <= 0), -1, 0))

print(df)
```

```
   close        rsi  low  high  signal  signal_diff  final_signal
0     100        NaN    0     0       0          NaN             0
1     110        NaN    0     0       0          0.0             0
2      90  17.391304    1     0       1          1.0             1
3     120  75.000000    0    -1      -1         -2.0             0
4     130  80.000000    0    -1      -1          0.0             0
5     140  85.714286    0    -1      -1          0.0             0
6     110  63.636364    0     0       0          1.0             0
7      90  34.782609    0     0       0          0.0             0
8      80  25.000000    1     0       1          1.0             1
9     100  54.545455    0     0       0         -1.0             0
10    120  84.210526    0    -1      -1         -1.0             0
```

Comment: THANKS :) but at index 5 rsi>80 and final_signal is 0, instead -1,  and at index 8 rsi is not less than 20, but signal 1 instead 0 can you please review thanks:)